# compiling a simple C++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

so basically i am trying to compile the famous Hello World program to test out an new IDE and a compiler. however it wont compile.

heres the code

```
// 'Hello World!' program

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the compile error report

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/bencawley/Documents/Bens Projects/Atom Projects/Test Project A/Scripts/Script A, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2F 0x2F 0x20 0x27 0x48 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F 0x20 0x57 0x6F 0x72 0x6C 0x64 0x21 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/bencawley/Documents/Bens Projects/Atom Projects/Test Project A/Scripts/Script A
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using GCC/G++ to compile the code
I am using ATOM.io as the IDE

Comment: if your file name is `script A` then rename it to `script A.cpp`.

Comment: You should carefully read your error message : **file was built for unsupported file format** . Rename it with **.cpp** at the end of it.

Comment: I would suggest that *"Script anything"* is a poor name for a program, firstly because it is not an interpreted script, rather a compiled executable/binary and secondly because having a space in the name of a program is generally asking for trouble.

Comment: Btw. the "Unsupported file format" is ASCII value string for `// 'Hello world!`. `ld` at this point thinks it's an **object**, i.e., an already translated file, rather than a source.